# How to get at least zero value from sum function of oracle pl/sql query

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi this is my query to get count of items

```
SELECT V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS.ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) RFPENDING,
       IMG "img"
FROM   V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION
       LEFT JOIN V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS
         ON V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS=V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS.ID
WHERE  V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS=5
AND    V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.CIRCLEID =(
         SELECT CIRCLEID
         FROM IMANAGERUSER 
         WHERE ID=:CURRENTUSERID
       )
GROUP BY V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS.ID,IMG;
```

if there is now row in `V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION` then there is no row in the result, but I want zero count if there is no row in the above table.
Can anybody help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 
        t2.ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t1.ISQSTATUS=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) RFPENDING,
        IMG
    FROM V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION t1
    LEFT JOIN V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS t2 ON t1.ISQSTATUS = t2.ID
    WHERE t1.ISQSTATUS = 5 
    AND t1.CIRCLEID = (
        SELECT CIRCLEID 
        FROM IMANAGERUSER 
        WHERE ID=:CURRENTUSERID
    ) 
    GROUP BY t2.ID, IMG
)
SELECT id, RFPENDING, IMG
FROM data

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, 0, NULL
FROM dual
WHERE 0 = (SELECT Count(id) FROM data);
```

Here `SELECT NULL, 0, NULL` get executed when the `Count(id) = 0`
i.e `no row` is returned by the first `select query`

Comment: Thanks @Praveen, But my query is a bit different form yours:

`WITH TBL AS 
(SELECT V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS,SUM(CASE WHEN V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)RFPENDING
FROM V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION
WHERE V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS=5 AND V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.CIRCLEID=(SELECT CIRCLEID FROM IMANAGERUSER 
WHERE ID=:CURRENTUSERID) GROUP BY V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS)
SELECT V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS.ID,nvl(RFPENDING,0)RFPENDING,IMG "img"
FROM V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS
LEFT JOIN TBL ON TBL.ISQSTATUS=V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS.ID
WHERE V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS.ID=5;`
It has better performance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the conditions for the outer table in the join:

```
SELECT V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS.ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)RFPENDING,
       IMG "img"
FROM V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION
LEFT JOIN V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS 
          ON V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS=V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS.ID
          AND V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.ISQSTATUS=5 
          AND V2_ISQ_DASBRD_AQSTION.CIRCLEID=(SELECT CIRCLEID FROM IMANAGERUSER 
                                              WHERE ID=:CURRENTUSERID) 
GROUP BY V2_SA_ISQ_STATUS.ID,IMG;
```

(NB It isn't compulsory to write your SQL all in uppercase by the way!)

Comment: I think there is no data at driving table either

Comment: In that case, what would you expect to see in the other 2 columns?

Comment: I'd go with @Praveen's answer.

Comment: @Praveen's answer gives the result but it is time consuming, the query is slow.